# How to prevent some command to history in shell

Tags: emacs

I run shell in emacs/windows. The commands will go to ~/.history. However, I don't want some commands be stored in .history, for example, "cd c:/..". How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

this is done with bash configuration. Write in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export HISTIGNORE="&:ls:cd:lh"
```

I also like the trick to not store in the history a command beginning with a space:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

or don't save duplicates:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
```

Now it depends also on what shell you are running. Usually the default one is bash. See with `echo $SHELL`. We can change it with the command `chsh` (change shell).